# create user with email and password and put data in database Fire base

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create users with the function createUserWithEmailAndPassword and then put the data of that user into my database but it doesn't work.. the user is added to my authentication tab in firebase but not in my database. I also don't get an error.

```
btn_reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override `enter code here`
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  String n=name.getText().toString().trim();
                  String u=username.getText().toString().trim();
                  String e=email.getText().toString().trim();
                  String ph=phone.getText().toString().trim();
                  String p=password.getText().toString().trim();

                  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(e,p).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                         if(task.isSuccessful()){
                             UserClass u=new UserClass(name,username,email,phone,password);
                             FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                     .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                     .setValue(u).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                 @Override
                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "User Created ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                                 }
                             });
                         }
                         else{
                             Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,task.getException().getMessage(), 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                      }
                  });
              }
          });
```

Comment: Do you have any debugging data? Second `onComplete` handler gets executed or not?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I believe that your path is wrong.. As far as I know, it has to be:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())....
```